# Count second highest no of conversation between two clients

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection called email with three fields say id, emailFrom, emailTo

now emailTo fields is an array

```
--------------------------------------------------
| id | emailFrom        | EmailTo                |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1  | A                | [B,C,D,B]              |
--------------------------------------------------
| 2  | B                | [A,C,D]                |
--------------------------------------------------
| 3  | A                | [B,C]                  |
--------------------------------------------------
| 4  | C                | [A]                    |
--------------------------------------------------
| 5  | B                | [C,C,A,D,E,F]          |
--------------------------------------------------
| 6  | A                | [C,B]                  |
--------------------------------------------------
| 7  | A                | [B,F,E,I]              |
--------------------------------------------------
```

**now my question is , how to find out the SECOND highest conversation between two clients**

*i.e. A send mail to B and B send mail to A, it means they have conversation of count 2.
and if A send a mail to B twice or thrice, it should be counted as well
now,*
**I want to find that which users have send most emails to each other**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the aggregation framework as following:

1. unwind by emailTo
2. group by emailFrom & emailTo to get unique convertations
3. in the group by sum the unique convertations
4. sort descending the sum from the previous step
5. skip the first result (optional)
6. limit to one (optional)

Try something like that:

```
use test;

db.mails.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$emailData.emailTo"},
    {$group: {
        _id: {
            "From": "$emailData.emailFrom",
            "To": "$emailData.emailTo"
        },
        _totalMailsSent: {$sum:1}
    }},
    {$sort: {_totalMailsSent:-1}},
    {$limit: 5}
])
```

Let me know if you still don't get it. Good luck ;).

Comment: @user2531799 try to implement the above steps. It is better to solve it by yourself.

Comment: Can you please provide me the query for this

Comment: I think you question is [this](https://education.10gen.com/courses/10gen/M101J/2013_May/courseware/Final_Exam/Question_2/). Am I right? I will not give the answer directly. Please try it yourself. Post here what have tried so far and I then will you help solve it. :)

Comment: db.email.aggregate([{$unwind:"emailData.emailTo"},{$group:{"_id":{"to","$emailData.emailTo","from":"$emailData.emailFrom"},totalEmails:{$sum:1}}},{$sort:{totalEmails:-1}},{$limit:5}])

Comment: That's correct, just change to `"$emailData.emailTo"` (don't forget the '$') in the `unwind`. Have you tried it? It should work.

Comment: I put the $ sign in $emailData.emailTo, actually this is my JSON doc

{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4f16fc97d1e2d32371003f02"),
  
  "emailData" : {
    "emailFrom" : "a@c.com",
    "To" :[ "c@c.com","d@c.com"]
  },
 
}

/* 1 */
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4f16fc97d1e2d32371003f02"),
  
  "emailData" : {
    "emailFrom" : "c@c.com",
    "To" : ["a@c.com","a@c.com","d@c.com","v@c.com","d@c.com","b@c.com"]
  },
 
}

Comment: Ok This is my new query                                                    
db.email.aggregate([{$unwind:"$emailData.emailTo"},{$group:{"_id":{"to":"$emailDa‌​ta.emailTo","from":"$emailData.emailFrom"},totalEmails:{$sum:1}}},{$sort:{totalEm‌​ails:-1}},{$limit:5}]) , It is giving the result 0,

Comment: Finally it works... I was making small mistake, thanks for your help , I am really having a big relief now only because of you, Thanks again,
God Bless You